# Count number of rows that are not within 10 seconds of each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I track web visitors. I store the IP address as well as the timestamp of the visit.

```
ip_address    time_stamp
180.2.79.3  1301654105
180.2.79.3  1301654106
180.2.79.3  1301654354
180.2.79.3  1301654356
180.2.79.3  1301654358
180.2.79.3  1301654366
180.2.79.3  1301654368
180.2.79.3  1301654422
```

I have a query to get total tracks:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tracks FROM tracking
```

However, I now want to disregard visits from users that have visited multiple times within 10 seconds of each visit. Since I don't consider this another visit, its still part of the first visit.

> When the ip_address is the same, check
>   timestamp and only count those rows
>   that are 10 seconds away from each
>   other.

I am having difficulty in putting this into a SQL query form, I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: If I have a entries for 23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35 does this count as two visits or one?

Comment: I appears that he's counting it as 2 visits, going by comments on answers.  But this seems very, preculiar, to me.

Comment: For me to even get started, i would need @MatthieuF's question answered. That's the key answer to understand the requirement. Without that I can't even vote for an existing answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me start with this table. I'll use ordinary timestamps so we can easily see what's going on.

```
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:00
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:09
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:20
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:23
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:25
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:40
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:00
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:13
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:23
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:25
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:27
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:29
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:50
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to count these like this.

```
180.2.79.3   3
180.2.79.4   3
```

You can do that for each ip_address by selecting the maximum timestamp that is both

- greater than the current row's
  timestamp, and
- less than or equal to 10 seconds greater than the current row's timestamp.

Taking these two criteria together will introduce some nulls, which turn out to be really useful.

```
select ip_address, 
       t_s.time_stamp, 
       (select max(t.time_stamp) 
        from t_s t 
        where t.ip_address = t_s.ip_address 
          and t.time_stamp > t_s.time_stamp
          and t.time_stamp - t_s.time_stamp <= interval '10' second) next_page
from t_s 
group by ip_address, t_s.time_stamp
order by ip_address, t_s.time_stamp;

ip_address   time_stamp            next_page
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:00   2011-01-01 08:00:09
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:09   <null>
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:20   2011-01-01 08:00:25
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:23   2011-01-01 08:00:25
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:25   <null>
180.2.79.3   2011-01-01 08:00:40   <null>
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:00   <null>
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:13   2011-01-01 08:00:23
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:23   2011-01-01 08:00:29
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:25   2011-01-01 08:00:29
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:27   2011-01-01 08:00:29
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:29   <null>
180.2.79.4   2011-01-01 08:00:50   <null>
```

The timestamp that marks the end of a visit has a null for its own next_page. That's because no timestamp is less than or equal to time_stamp + 10 seconds for that row.

To get a count, I'd probably create a view and count the nulls.

```
select ip_address, count(*)
from t_s_visits 
where next_page is null
group by ip_address

180.2.79.3   3
180.2.79.4   3
```

Comment: There is a problem with this: what happens if you have an entry for 23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34? This is two visits, but you count it as one.

Comment: I think the OP wanted that to count as one visit; a 10 second gap between log entries identifies a second visit. Search this web page for "I didn't think about that". That's the OP's comment that clarified this point.

Comment: I'm not sure that what he said counts as a clarification :-) If he does want it counted as one visit then I think your SQL is correct.

Comment: It makes sense if you think about what a web visit means. Visitor hits one or more pages, stops hitting pages for 'n' seconds, starts hitting pages again.  The whole idea of "visits" is fuzzy nowadays; I've had a couple of pages open in tabs in my browser for two or three days. The web server can't tell whether or when I'm reading them.

Answer (score 6):

You could `JOIN` the tracking table to itself and filter out the records you don't need by adding a `WHERE`clause.

```
SELECT  t1.ip_address
        , COUNT(*) AS tracks
FROM    tracking t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking t2 ON t2.ip_address = t1.ip_address
                                       AND t2.time_stamp < t1.time_stamp + 10
WHERE   t2.ip_adress IS NULL
GROUP BY
        t1.ip_address
```

**Edit**

Following script works in SQL Server but I can't express it in a single SQL statement, let alone convert it to MySQL. It might give you some pointers on what is needed though.

*Note: I assume for given inputs, number 1 and 11 should get chosen.*

```
;WITH q (number) AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 10
  UNION ALL SELECT 11  
  UNION ALL SELECT 12
)
SELECT  q1.Number as n1
        , q2.Number as n2
        , 0 as Done
INTO    #Temp
FROM    q q1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN q q2 ON q2.number < q1.number + 10
                                AND q2.number > q1.number

DECLARE @n1 INTEGER
DECLARE @n2 INTEGER

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE Done = 0)
BEGIN

  SELECT  TOP 1 @n1 = n1
          , @n2= n2
  FROM    #Temp
  WHERE   Done = 0

  DELETE  FROM #Temp
  WHERE   n1 = @n2

  UPDATE  #Temp 
  SET     Done = 1
  WHERE   n1 = @n1 
          AND n2 = @n2         
END        

SELECT  DISTINCT n1 
FROM    #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: The tracks table is currently around 70000 rows and will grow significantly more. Will a join on itself be expensive in terms of performance? Not that I can come up with a better query!

Comment: @Lieven - whats the error? You mean the typo for the column `ip_address`?

Comment: @Abs, didn't even see that. No, I think it will not return what you need. Can you try it on a subset of the data to verify that?

Comment: @Lieven - I tested it and I added a condition in the on clause `AND site_id = 25`. When I ran this query it took a while and phpmyadmin reported mysql had gone away! I then tried just your query above and it took a while and went away again! I tested other queries in case it was my setup but they worked fine.

Comment: @Abs, what indices do you have on your table?  If not already there, an index on `(ip_address, time_stamp)` should make this self join quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to divide the timestamps by 10, and count the distinct combinations of those values and the ip_address values. That way each 10 second period is counted separately.

If you run this on your sample data it will give you 4 tracks, which is what you want I think.

Give it a try and see if it gives you the desired results on your full data set:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address, FLOOR(time_stamp/10)) AS tracks 
FROM tracking
```

Comment: I don't think the above will work. Say there is a log for the 19th second and the 21th second. If you floor it, it will be 10 and 20 and they will be both included even though they shouldn't since they are 2 seconds apart.

Comment: It all depends on your requirements, and I made some assumptions since you did not specify your desired output for your sample data set. What if you have a log for the 9th, 18th, 27th, 36th, 45th,  and 54th seconds. Would you count those 6 events as a single event since each is within 10 seconds of each other?

Comment: interesting, I didn't think about that. I was hoping if I got a (12th), (25th, 26th, 27th), (40th). That shound be a count of 3. Its even more complicated! How can I got about this?

Comment: There still might be a performance benefit to doing this, though, as a way to get an *initial* reduced list of candidates for then reducing further with a "proper" left join.

Comment: +1 for creative solution that does not require a self join. If you use ROUND(time_stamp / 10,0) you're pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Make a left join against the records with the same ip and a close time, and filter out the records where there is a match:

```
select count(*) as visits
from (
  select t.ip_address
  from tracking t
  left join tracking t2
    on t2.ip_address = t.ip_address
    and t2.timestamp > t.timestamp and t2.timestamp <= t.timestamp + 10
  where t2.ip_address is null
) x
```

Comment: I tried the above and for the above ip_addresses and time stamp, I get a count of 8? Shouldn't it be 4? Btw, I changed the query and added `t.ip_address` for the second select statement.

Comment: @Abs: I corrected the query. You are correct that the selected fields needs a table specifier. Also, the query did not filter out the records where there is a match, as the descriptions says, it did the opposite, so it counted only revisits, and multiple times. Now the query should match the description.

Comment: @Guffa - thank you for the update. I am unsure if there is a problem with my mysql setup or the query. Every time I run it, like @liven's query, mysql seems to just go away after it thinks for a bit! Btw, Where would be the best place to put this condition `AND site_id = 20`, it should cut down the number of rows being investigated, within the `on` clause?

Comment: @Abs: That behaviour is not normal for any query, there has to be something wrong with your software, likely your GUI. You would place a condition like that both in the `where` condition and the `on` condition, so that you filter the table both times it's used.

Comment: @Guffa - its strange, I keep getting that error. But when I put that condition in the `where` and `on` it executed fine but with a count of 0. Maybe this query dies because its joining a large table to itself?

Comment: @Abs: No, joining large tables is exactly what the database is built to do, it's practically impossible to overload it that way.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with SQL there are many solution for your problem.
I would use following query which is simple and should be "good enough":

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tracks 
FROM (
    SELECT ip_address 
    FROM tracking 
    GROUP BY ip_address, FLOOR(time_stamp / 10)
)
```

The sub query groups visits of a single user in 10s intervals so that they are counted as one visit.

Of cause it is possible to find cases in which two visits will appear in different 10s window even though the interval between this visits will be less than 10s. It would require much more complex logic to eliminate such cases and the analytical value of this added complexity would be dubious (10s interval sounds like an arbitrary value anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Z.IP, Count(*) As VisitCount
From    (
        Select V.IP
        From visitors As V
            Left Join visitors As V2
                On V2.IP = V.IP
                    And V2.time_stamp > V.time_stamp
        Group By V.IP, V.time_stamp
        Having (Min(V2.time_stamp) - V.time_stamp) >= 10
        ) As Z
Group By Z.IP
```

This counts any visit where the next entry is more than 10 seconds away as a new visit.

Answer (score 0):

The following logic will only count a visit as a 'unique visit' if there wasn't a preceding record from the same ip address within the preceding 10 seconds.

This means that {1,11,21,32,42,52,62,72} will count as 2 visits, with 3 and 5 tracks each, respectively.

It accomplishes this by first identifying the unique visits.  Then it counts all visits that happened between that unique visit and the next unique visit.

```
WITH
    unique_visits
(
  SELECT
    ip_address, time_stamp
  FROM
    visitors
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM visitors AS [previous]
                WHERE ip_address  = visitors.ip_address
                  AND time_stamp >= visitors.timestamp - 10
                  AND time_stamp <  visitors.timestamp)
)
SELECT
  unique_visitors.ip_address,
  unique_visitors.time_stamp,
  COUNT(*) AS [total_tracks]
FROM
  unique_visitors
INNER JOIN
  visitors
    ON  visitors.ip_address  = unique_visitors.ip_address
    AND visitors.time_stamp >= unique_visitors.time_stamp
    AND visitors.time_stamp <  ISNULL(
                                  (SELECT MIN(time_stamp) FROM unique_visitors [next]
                                   WHERE  ip_address = unique_visitors.ip_address
                                   AND    time_stamp > unique_visitors.ip_address)
                                  , visitors.time_stamp + 1
                               )
```

You will also want either an index or primary key on (ip_address, time_stamp)

Answer (score 0):

For giggles sakes, here is an UPDATE hack that accomplishes what you need. There are a myriad of reasons not to implement this, including but not limited to the fact that it may simply stop working some day. Anyway, assuming you have your table initially ordered by ip -> timestamp, this should (usually) give you the correct answers. Again, this is for completeness, if you implement this, look [up the risks beforehand](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/fa337bbf-1721-44e3-8b79-e02431154df1).

```
CREATE TABLE #TestIPs
(
    ip_address varchar(max),
    time_stamp decimal(12,0),
    cnt int
    )

INSERT INTO #TestIPs (ip_address, time_stamp)
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654105 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654106 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654354 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654356 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654358 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654366 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654368 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.3',  1301654422 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654105 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654106 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654354 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654356 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654358 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654366 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654368 UNION ALL
SELECT '180.2.79.4',  1301654422

DECLARE @count int; SET @count = 0
DECLARE @ip varchar(max); SET @ip = 'z'
DECLARE @timestamp decimal(12,0); SET @timestamp = 0;

UPDATE #TestIPs
    SET @count = cnt = CASE WHEN time_stamp - @timestamp > 10 THEN @count + 1 ELSE CASE WHEN @ip <> ip_address THEN 1 ELSE @count END END,      
        @timestamp = time_stamp,
        @ip = ip_address


        SELECT ip_address, MAX(cnt) AS 'Visits' FROM #TestIPs GROUP BY ip_address
```

Results:

```
ip_address  Visits
------------ -----------
180.2.79.3  3
180.2.79.4  3
```