# Records with time stamps 10 seconds a part

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some SQL data in a table running MySQL and below is what it looks like when I export with MySQL WorkBench.

I saw the [Count number of rows that are not within 10 seconds of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512714/count-number-of-rows-that-are-not-within-10-seconds-of-each-other) post and tried applying it accordingly here but I couldn't easily figure it out so I'm posting as a question for some help.

---

### Starting Data

*This is the data I start this in a table*

> **Column Headers**
>
> TimeInt, TimeStr, IsInItValue, Value, IQuality

**Data**

```
'1495542477', '2017-05-23 12:27:57', '0', '0', '3'
'1495542475', '2017-05-23 12:27:55', '0', '1', '3'
'1495542474', '2017-05-23 12:27:54', '0', '3', '3'
'1495542473', '2017-05-23 12:27:53', '0', '4', '3'
'1495542472', '2017-05-23 12:27:52', '0', '5', '3'
'1495542471', '2017-05-23 12:27:51', '0', '4', '3'
'1495542470', '2017-05-23 12:27:50', '0', '3', '3'
'1495447612', '2017-05-22 10:06:52', '0', '1', '3'
'1495447611', '2017-05-22 10:06:51', '0', '2', '3'
'1494851001', '2017-05-15 12:23:21', '0', '2', '3'
'1493819613', '2017-05-03 13:53:33', '0', '0', '3'
'1493819612', '2017-05-03 13:53:32', '0', '1', '3'
'1493819611', '2017-05-03 13:53:31', '0', '2', '3'
'1493819609', '2017-05-03 13:53:29', '0', '4', '3'
'1493819608', '2017-05-03 13:53:28', '0', '6', '3'
'1493819607', '2017-05-03 13:53:27', '0', '5', '3'
'1493819606', '2017-05-03 13:53:26', '0', '4', '3'
'1493819605', '2017-05-03 13:53:25', '0', '2', '3'
'1493819603', '2017-05-03 13:53:23', '0', '1', '3'
```

---

I'd like to see if there's a way to join this data to itself or apply some logic with a sub query, etc. so I could get values back or easily distinguish the data where the time stamp for the very next row in this table is greater than 10 seconds.

The method of one of the answers on the post I linked to above uses a method where the records with `NULL` values would be helpful but I couldn't get it to work with MySQL.

I tried a variation from the answer on the [Count number of rows that are not within 10 seconds of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512714/count-number-of-rows-that-are-not-within-10-seconds-of-each-other) post but couldn't figure out where I was going wrong but below one of the few things I tried. I'm not sure if the `interval` is still valid since that was from 2011 or I'm doing something else incorrectly to get syntax errors but this is one of the things I tried.

```
SELECT t2.TimeStr, Value, 
(SELECT MAX(t.TimeStr) 
        FROM canouncebit t 
        WHERE t.TimeStr > t2.TimeStr
          AND t.TimeStr - t2.TimeStr <= interval '10' second) NextRecord
FROM canouncebit t2
ORDER BY TimeStr
```

---

### Expected Data (or something close enough)

*I'd like to end up with something like this or even somewhat close I can use*

**Data**

```
'1495542477', '2017-05-23 12:27:57', '0', '0', '3'
'1495447612', '2017-05-22 10:06:52', '0', '1', '3'
'1494851001', '2017-05-15 12:23:21', '0', '2', '3'
'1493819613', '2017-05-03 13:53:33', '0', '0', '3'
```

So basically I only need to get the data back and the value in particular for only the records where that value has been in place for more than `X` seconds (10 in this case).

---

### Create Table Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `ContainerOzBit` (
  `TimeInt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TimeStr` datetime NOT NULL,
  `IsInitValue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` float NOT NULL,
  `IQuality` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `TimeInt` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

### Insert Data Statement

```
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542477','2017-05-23 12:27:57',0,0,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542475','2017-05-23 12:27:55',0,1,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542474','2017-05-23 12:27:54',0,3,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542473','2017-05-23 12:27:53',0,4,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542472','2017-05-23 12:27:52',0,5,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542471','2017-05-23 12:27:51',0,4,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495542470','2017-05-23 12:27:50',0,3,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495447612','2017-05-22 10:06:52',0,1,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1495447611','2017-05-22 10:06:51',0,2,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1494851001','2017-05-15 12:23:21',0,2,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819613','2017-05-03 13:53:33',0,0,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819612','2017-05-03 13:53:32',0,1,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819611','2017-05-03 13:53:31',0,2,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819609','2017-05-03 13:53:29',0,4,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819608','2017-05-03 13:53:28',0,6,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819607','2017-05-03 13:53:27',0,5,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819606','2017-05-03 13:53:26',0,4,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819605','2017-05-03 13:53:25',0,2,3);
INSERT INTO `ContainerOzBit` (`TimeInt`,`TimeStr`,`IsInitValue`,`Value`,`IQuality`) VALUES ('1493819603','2017-05-03 13:53:23',0,1,3);
```

Comment: Nearly. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry - Sorry about that, I think I cleaned it up a bit but didn't have time to put the data in SQLFilddle so I hope the insert statement and showing the other query is enough to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to leverage MySQL's session variables:

```sql
-- omit the duplicated timeint that we used in the derived table
SELECT c.* FROM (
  -- grab the maximum timeint value in the group
  SELECT MAX(timeint) timeint FROM (
    SELECT timeint, -- current row's timeint value
           -- if diff betwen current and prev values more than 10 sec 
           -- increment the group number, otherwise keep it the same
           @g := IF(timeint - @p > 10, @g + 1, @g) g, 
           -- preserve the the value so it's available on the next iteration
           @p := timeint 
      FROM ContainerOzBit CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT @p := NULL, @g := 1 -- initialize sesion variables
      ) i
     -- deterministic order is crucial for this approach
     -- since we're iteration row by row
     ORDER BY timeint
  ) q
  -- group by the group number 
   GROUP BY g
   -- since timeint values are unique 
   -- join back and retrieve all the columns
) r JOIN ContainerOzBit c 
   ON r.timeint = c.timeint
   -- set the reverse order for the result set
 ORDER BY timeint DESC;
```

*Read comments from the inner most select going outward*

Result:

```
+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| TimeInt    | TimeStr             | IsInitValue | Value | IQuality |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 1495542477 | 2017-05-23 12:27:57 |           0 |     0 |        3 |
| 1495447612 | 2017-05-22 10:06:52 |           0 |     1 |        3 |
| 1494851001 | 2017-05-15 12:23:21 |           0 |     2 |        3 |
| 1493819613 | 2017-05-03 13:53:33 |           0 |     0 |        3 |
+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8068c0bc62e160dff1c822f0d6b49590) demo

Comment: Thanks @peterm, I'll be digging into this for sure.

Comment: Sure. Just added comments for you explaining how this query works.

Comment: Very nice and much more efficient than adding DATE_ADD() function, etc. Nice indeed, very helpful, and very informative as well!!